# How to get direction from visitor's current location to my location in embedded google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, maps

I have got an embedded map on my website which contains a marker point to my office address. However, I need users to be presented with the directions from their current location to my office location automatically through geolocation in web browser. Is it possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Find a route using Geolocation and Google Maps API</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function calculateRoute(from, to) {
        // Center initialized to Naples, Italy
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.84, 14.25),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        // Draw the map
        var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsRequest = {
          origin: from,
          destination: to,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
        };
        directionsService.route(
          directionsRequest,
          function(response, status)
          {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
            {
              new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                map: mapObject,
                directions: response
              });
            }
            else
              $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
          }
        );
      }

      $(document).ready(function() {
        // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
        if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
          $("#error").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
          return;
        }

        $("#from-link, #to-link").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var addressId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("-"));

          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({
              "location": new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
            },
            function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                $("#" + addressId).val(results[0].formatted_address);
              else
                $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your address<br />");
            });
          },
          function(positionError){
            $("#error").append("Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />");
          },
          {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
          });
        });

        $("#calculate-route").submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          calculateRoute($("#from").val(), "govandi"));
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Calculate your route</h1>
    <form id="calculate-route" name="calculate-route" action="#" method="get">
      <label for="from">From:</label>
      <input type="text" id="from" name="from" required="required" placeholder="An address" size="30" />
      <a id="from-link" href="#">Get my position</a>
      <br />

      <label for="to">To:</label>
      <input type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="Another address" size="30" />
      <a id="to-link" href="#">Get my position</a>
      <br />

      <input type="submit" />
      <input type="reset" />
    </form>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <p id="error"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible? Uhm, yes, everything is possible. The biggest question is how much time do you want to spend on it? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @SZenC I looked into tutorials but most of them either showed how to enable geolocation or predefined route but not combined.

Comment: And you are not able to combine those 2?

Comment: @SZenC I've added the code sample

Comment: @Dr.Molle Embedded maps means the map inserted on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

I've slightly amended the code from https://www.sitepoint.com/find-a-route-y using-the-geolocation-and-the-google-maps-api/ to have a journey planner from user location to set destinations, using a select html form.

In case it is useful for anyone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Find a route using Geolocation and Google Maps API</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
  function calculateRoute(from, to) {
    // Center initialized somewhere near London
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    // Draw the map
    var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsRequest = {
      origin: from,
      destination: to,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    };
    directionsService.route(
      directionsRequest,
      function(response, status)
      {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
        {
          new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: mapObject,
            directions: response
          });
        }
        else
          $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
      }
    );
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
    if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
      $("#error").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
      return;
    }

    $("#from-link, #to-link").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var addressId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("-"));

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
          "location": new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
        },
        function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            $("#" + addressId).val(results[0].formatted_address);
          else
            $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your address<br />");
        });
      },


      function(positionError){
        $("#error").append("Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />");
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
      });
    });

    $("#calculate-route").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      calculateRoute($("#from").val(), $("#to").val());
    });


  });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  #map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Calculate your route</h1>
  <form id="calculate-route" name="calculate-route" action="#" method="get">
  <label for="from">From:</label>
  <input type="text" id="from" name="from" required="required" placeholder="An address" size="30" />
  <a id="from-link" href="#">Get my position</a>
  <br />

  <label for="to">To:</label>
  <select id="to">
    <option value="51.5548885,-0.108438">Arsenal's Emirates Stadium</option>
    <option value="51.481663,-0.1931505">Chelsea's Stamford Bridge</option>
  </select>

  <br />

  <input type="submit" />
  <input type="reset" />
</form>
<div id="map"></div>
<p id="error"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Find a route using Geolocation and Google Maps API</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function calculateRoute(from, to) {
             var myLatLng = {lat: 19.056, lng: 72.921};

            // Center initialized to Mumbai, India
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            // Draw the map
            var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);





            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsRequest = {
                origin: from,
                destination: to,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
            };
            directionsService.route(
                directionsRequest,
                function (response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                            map: mapObject,
                            directions: response
                        });

                        $('.distance-in-km').text(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000 + "km");

                        alert( response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000 + "km" ); // the distance in metres
                    } else
                        $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your route<br />");
                }
            );
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
            if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
                $("#error").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
                return;
            }

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode({
                            "location": new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
                        },
                        function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                calculateRoute(results[0].formatted_address, "govandi");
                            } else {
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: myLatLng,
                                    title: 'Hello World!'
                                  });

                                marker.setMap(mapObject);

                                $("#error").append("Unable to retrieve your address<br />");
                            }
                        });
                });



                calculateRoute($("#from").val(), "govandi");

            $("#calculate-route").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();



                calculateRoute($("#from").val(), "govandi");
            });


            $('.verify-location > a').click(function(){
                $('.verify-location').hide();
                $('#calculate-route').show();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        #calculate-route {
            display: none;
        }
        .verify-location > a {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #FCA2A2;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="verify-location">Is the your location incorrect? <a>Click here to enter your location manually</a></div>
    <form id="calculate-route" name="calculate-route" action="#" method="get">
        <label for="from">From:</label>
        <input type="text" id="from" name="from" placeholder="An address" size="30" />
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <p id="error"></p>
    <p class="distance-in-km"></p>
</body>

</html>
```